# D7 equivalent to AutoMenu module

Tags: 7, routes

In the past I always ensured that I had [AutoMenu module](https://drupal.org/project/automenu) installed on any Drupal 6 site I created. This module afforded me the following:

- The ability to auto-create the menu item entry (per content type) when a new node is created (instead of manually clicking `Provide a menu link`), and
- (optionally) Automatically set the newly created menu item to `disabled`.

These 2 features with D6 sites have always allowed me to not worry about another content-editor users messing up the hierarchy of the site. Plus it played well with my menus and breadcrumbs.

I have been desperately trying to get similar functionality working in D7, but haven't had much luck so far. There was an unofficial port of the said module to D7 but after trying it, it gave some errors.

Please can you suggest a way in Drupal 7 for me to achieve the same? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module has a drupal 7 version in the issue queue at https://drupal.org/node/1138946

Comment #25 has a link to a sandbox of the drupal 7 port: https://drupal.org/sandbox/wojtha/1331132

There is another version in a zip file at comment #46 but it seems that one is inferior.

It seems that it has been reviewed by a few people and works but the module doesn't seem to have an active maintainer so it has not been committed to the repository and made available on the project page.

I would try those versions of the module and see if either of them work.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is the unofficial port I referred to in my post. While it does do most of the things AutoMenu did in D6, it does not automatically disable new menu items created under a parent item.

Comment: Oh ok. I would say those links are your best chance. If you are a coder I would start with those and fix any issues. otherwise see if you can get some movement in that issue and get someone else to work on it. Sometimes you get lucky but not always.

Comment: Ok thanks rooby. I'll upvote your response, but I'll leave it open for now if you don't mind, just to get some additional input from the community.

Comment: Sure, no worries